# Sharing question from mobile app (android)

Tags: discussion, android-app, sharing

I had the following case today:
I've set up my app to open every SO overflow from the browser, but I wanted to share a question with a friend to discuss some topic about a programming approach, the issue was that I wasn't enabled to share the question within the app, it would be great if we could have a **"share feature"** that could pass the url to other application like what's app, mail or any social network.

the workaround was to hold the link in the browser and open it in a different tab and share the link from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tap on the three vertical dots next to a question's timestamp (on the far right of the user's info) and you can share or do any other action you would like onto the question.

This obviously is really hidden, and we are aware of that. We're trying to figure out a better place to put this to make it more obvious, the normal places (action bar, for instance) don't work since we use the exact same mechanism for sharing an answer. It'll hopefully be improved soon, but suggestions are dearly welcome.

Comment: thanks.. it's not easy to figure it out probably if you move the three dots next to the question title it would be better to "see" the icon...

Comment: @Pedro Yep, but then where would they go for answers?

Comment: @Pedro I guess the reason why it is put below is to follow the web design. On the other hand, Android users who are already used to ActionBar will expect the share button *somewhere* around the top, I agree. However, as Kasra said, they cannot do that for answers, and it will make design inconsistency which is not good either.

Comment: hey guys fair point... it's easier just to give an oponion without thinking too much...now looking from that perspective makes more sense to have the button on that location...however I still think that the three dots icon should be different or stand out a little bit more because it's hard to see it, anyway thanks for putting the effort to read and analyse the suggestions from us (the users) that says a lot from you guys....keep up the good work ... cheers

Comment: @Pedro yep, definitely agree. We've spent lots of time trying to figure out *where* to move that action to and what the icon for it should be. Hopefully we'll come up with something better soon.

Comment: The "Edited" text threw me off on this. Probably a good start would be to have the Share (question/post version) in the context menu.. it was the second place i looked

Comment: @MattR by context menu do you mean when long-clicking the question's title or what?

Comment: I was talking about the menu when you click the devices menu key. The one with the `Settings` and `Help` options.